# Impact of bottling in plastic on beer taste

Tags: bottling, taste

Beer is commonly bottled in plastic bottles in Germany. Does drinking beer from plastic have some negative impact on beer taste?

Or are the materials from which the bottles are made chosen so that they don't interact chemically with beer, or in any way change the taste?

Comment: In Germany, beer in plastic bottle is not common at all.

Answer (score 2):

Provided all the bottling equipment was properly sanitised (which you'd hope was the case for commercial beer), you shouldn't notice any impact on the taste of the beer.

That said, plastic bottles do not provide as good a seal as a crown sealed glass bottle.  If you store the beer for long enough (say six months to a year), a plastic bottle will have lost some of its carbonation.  If you stick to the "drink by" date on commercial beer though, this shouldn't be a problem.